# How to access a localhost website from another computer?

Tags: html, web, localhost

I am building my own website and I want to show my brother on the same network. But localhost is only on my computer... I think at least. Is there a way I ca nhost it on the network instead of my computer?

Comment: Instead of `http://localhost/`, simply use your computer name: `http://<your-computer-name-here>`.

Answer (score 0):

To access your localhost site from another computer, you can use the IP address of the computer on your local network where the site is located (for example: `http://192.168.0.2/`) instead of `http://localhost/` or `http://127.0.0.1/` which is the same thing.

If you are unable to do this due to a 404 or 403 error, check your web server configuration and/or firewall configuration.